# Is there any problem with this code?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello.";

    ifstream attack,output;

    attack.open("CattackList");
    output.open("finaltestOutput.txt");

    if (!attack)
        cout << "file1 not opened.\n";
    if (!output)
        cout << "file2 not opened.\n";

    char buf1[100],buf2[100];
    attack.getline(buf1,100);

    int count = 0, C=0;

    cout << "hello";

    while (!attack.eof())
    {
        C++;

        cout << "ok";

        output.open("finaltestOutput");

        while (!output.eof())
        {
            output.getline(buf2, 80);
            if (strncmp(buf1, buf2, 51) == 0)
            {
                cout << buf2 << endl;
                count++;
            }
        }
        attack.getline(buf1, 80);
    }
    cout << "\nTotal Attacks : " << C << endl;
    cout << "Attacks detected: " << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to get even the first "Hello" to get printed...

Comment: Seems to be "fine" atleast with printing the first "Hello". See http://codepad.org/FVkpiUQS

Comment: Did you get any compiler errors? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
```

Please put a space after each `#include`.

```
if (!attack)
    cout << "file1 not opened.\n";
if (!output)
    cout << "file2 not opened.\n";
```

Error messages should go to `cerr`, not `cout`.

```
char buf1[100],buf2[100];
attack.getline(buf1,100);
```

Did you allow space for the null at the end of the string? Also, one space after each comma.

```
int count = 0, C=0;
```

Spaces around binary operators such as `=`. Also, single letter variable names are discouraged.

```
    output.open("finaltestOutput");
```

You already opened this file. Why are you opening it again? Also, points off for naming an input file stream `output`.

```
        output.getline(buf2, 80);
        if (strncmp(buf1, buf2, 51) == 0)
```

Where are you getting the numbers `80` and `51`?

There may be more; start with that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any problem with this code?

1. It's C++ not C.
2. The indentation is broken.
3. Stick to one statement per line.
4. It is full of inexplicable magic constants.

Sort those problems out first and then ask again.

Comment: Would have been better as a comment.

Comment: @muntoo Hardly. There's not much more that can be said about this code.

Answer (score 0):

In, your code you dint given the Filename Extensions at two parts one is at `attack.open("CattackList");` and the other is at `output.open("finaltestOutput");`. May be this causing the files not to be Opened and getting the unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks a lot.My problem got solved.The problem came with opening the same file twice with the same file handler.